# Most common "denominators" in a two column list in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

How can I find the most commonly found 'Code' (Col B) associated with each unique 'Name' in (Col A) and find the closest value if the 'Code' in Col B is unique?

The image below shows the [shared google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CY5SV2_J5GsM_96stsqBq3Abwvs9pIepfcIaaTGnJPA/edit?usp=sharing) with Starting data in Columns A & B and the desired output columns in columns C and D. Each Unique Name has associated codes.  Column D displays the most commonly occuring Code for each unique name. For example, Buick La Sabre 1 has 3 associated codes in B3,B4,B5 but in D3 only 98761 because it appears more frequently than the other 2 codes do in B2:B. I will explain what I mean by the closest value below.

The Codes that have a count = 1 are unique so the output in column D tries to find the closest match.

However, when the count of the code in B2:B > 1, then the output in column D = to the most frequent code associated with the Name.

[image]
**Approach when there is 2 or more of the same values in column B**

1. Query

I thought I might use a QUERY with a `ORDER BY count(B) DESC LIMIT 2` in a fashion similar to this working equation:

```
QUERY($A$1:$D$25,"SELECT A, B ORDER BY B DESC Limit 2",1)
```

but I could not get it to work when I substituted in the Count function.

2. SORT & INDEX OR VLOOKUP

If the query function can't be fixed to work, then I thought another approach might be to combine a Vlookup/Index after sorting column B in a descending order.

```
UNIQUE(sort($B$3:$B,if(len($B$3:$B),countif($B$3:$B,$B$3:$B),),0,1,1))
```

Since a Vlookup or Index using multiple criteria would just pull the first value it finds, you would just end up with the first matching value, we would then get the most frequent value.

**Approach when there is < 2 of the same values in column B**
This is a little more complicated since the values can be numbers and letters.

A solution like that seen in the image below could be used if everything were a number. In our case there will usually be between 3 - 5 character alphanumeric code starting with 0 - 1 letters  numbers and followed by numbers. I'm not sure what the best way to match a code like A1234 would be. I imagine a solution might be to SPLIT off letters and trying to match those first. For example A1234 would be split into A | 1234, then matching the closest letter and then the closest number. But I really am not sure what the best solution to this might be that works within the constraints of Google Sheets.

[image]

In the event that a number is equidistant between two numbers, the lower number should be chosen. For example, if 8 is the number and the closest match would be 6 or 10, then 6 should be selected.

In the event that a letter is being used it should work in a similar fashion. For example, thinking of {A, B, C} as {1, 2, 3},  B should preferrentially match to A since it comes before C.

In summary, looking for a way to  find the most frequently associated code in col B that is associated with unique names in col A in [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CY5SV2_J5GsM_96stsqBq3Abwvs9pIepfcIaaTGnJPA/edit?usp=sharing) and; In the event where there are none of the same codes in B2:B, a formula that will find the closest match for a number or alphanumeric code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula:

```
=QUERY({range of numerators & denominators}, "select Col2, count(Col2) group by Col2 label Col2 'Denominator', count(Col2) 'Count'")
```

That outputs something like this:

| Denominator | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Den 1 | Count 1 |
| Den 2 | Count 2 |

Comment: RE. QUERY({(A2:B26)}, "select Col2, count(Col2) group by Col2 label Col2 'Code', count(Col2) 'Count'") but this doesnt sort in descending order or add Col1, which if I add QUERY({(A2:B26)}, "select Col1, Col2, count(Col2) group by Col1 label Col1 'Name', Col2 label Col2 'Code', count(Col2) 'Count'") it doesn't work. Unsure why,

Comment: remove the parentheses around the range and try again. I updated the answer

Comment: unsure I understand. Can you enter into spreadsheet? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CY5SV2_J5GsM_96stsqBq3Abwvs9pIepfcIaaTGnJPA/edit#gid=1751437552

Comment: It should look like this: `=QUERY({A2:B26}, "select Col2, count(Col2) group by Col2 label Col2 'Code', count(Col2) 'Count'")`

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORTN(QUERY({A3:B}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,count(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null
  group by Col1,Col2 
  order by count(Col2) desc,Col2 asc 
  label count(Col2)''"), 9^9, 2, 1, 1), 9^9, 2)
```

[image]

Comment: I think I need to clarify that the closest match need only be found when the only codes that are associated with a given name occur only 1x.  The general equation which finds the closest match for a number (which doesnt account for any alphabetical charecters) is the lowest absolute value difference  AND the lowest number. In the case of an alphanumerical code, I am not sure about the best method to find yet. I added a count and comments to the spreadsheet to show any differences between the desired output and the output from the equation, but I admit to this being hard to explain.